# Error on simple MySQL query using Python, but works in MySQL console?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run a simple insert query to a database. I have it configured correctly, and it should work, but it doesn't. For some reason I get the following error on this query:

Query:

```
INSERT INTO searches (query) VALUES ('test')
```

Error:

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'query'")
```

The query runs without problems in the MySQL console so it must be a problem with Python? Here's my Python code:

```
def increase_search_count(search_query):
    from django.db import connection, transaction

    search_query = search_query.strip()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    rows = cursor.execute("INSERT INTO searches (query) VALUES ('test')")
```

I know there are much better ways to handle databases, but I'm new to Python, and I have a deadline. I'd just like to get this to work, I have another SELECT query in another function and that one runs without any problems!

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that query is constructed means you will always be inserting 'test' into the database, and seeing the query is likely the primary key in your table, it will be creating duplicate rows.

The query should be something like "INSERT INTO searches (query) VALUES ('" variable "')" so you don't insert the same value over and over.